# Scheduled code execution in MVC3 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, cron-task

Consider we have a working computer support incident management web site developed with ASP.NET MVC3. Currently, support staff operators register support incidents manually.

I need to implement a scheduled unattended incident registration functionality. Basically introduce a class, which instance will be running all the time (when the web site is running of course) and based on internal logic will be adding new incidents to a data storage.

Where can I put such code, to be sure it's instance is in memory, operational at all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post of Phil Haack -ASP.NET MVC team- where he talks about it and shows best practices to do it.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to run scheduled tasks on asp.net site, you can use a open source project called

[Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)